# program uninstalled but still accessible

Tags: windows-10, uninstall

I have installed [IRIS Payroll Basics](https://www.iris.co.uk/support/knowledgebase/kb/11732/) to run company payroll.  IRIS didn't run great, and I replaced it with a different payroll app.

I uninstalled IRIS, but when I go into the Start menu, the program still appears, and if I click its icon, the program runs...

If I go into Add/Remove programs, the program does not appear, If I right-click its icon in the Start menu and select uninstall, it takes me to the control panel and again, there is no option for this program.

I also tried to reinstall the program and instead of installing, I selected to remove but still the program remains.

What else I can try to remove this from the system?

Comment: Maybe the uninstaller is faulty. You should try to reinstall it, then run Revo Uninstaller Free (here: https://www.revouninstaller.com/fr/revo-uninstaller-free-download/) to uninstall it for you. Once the built-in uninstaller has finished, go to the Advanced mode in the leftover scan window, and delete all the entries Revo will throw at you, then restart your PC. Your program should be gone for good now.

Comment: https://www.revouninstaller.com/products/revo-uninstaller-free/ is the English link for Francophobes.

Comment: @K7AAY : A) I don't see why anyone would be francophobe :-D ; and B) It's supposed to switch automatically according to your regional / linguistic preferences when you click on the link.

Comment: Regrettably, my IT-configured Chrome fails to switch to Anglais, go figure. And, you may have noticed there are a few folks who are adamantly English-only, here and there.

Comment: Oh oui, especially ici... Go comprendre... :-)

Comment: @Didier - It doesn't switch.  So best to provide links to websites so everything is English, as answers are indeed, suppose to be in English.

Comment: There's a (visible) flag in the top right corner for those who wish to see the page in a different language, plus the installer is multilingual, so there's no risk whatsoever to install something the end-user doesn't want to. This constant bickering only proves that some people here don't have an answer to the question that was asked, and start grasping at straws to save face...

Comment: @Didier Thank you, that seemed to work :-). And to resolve the argument that my question seems to have started... I followed your link and selected the flag at the top and changed to UK without any issues :-)

Comment: Happy to have been of assistance, in any language... :-)